# Missing Node Label Indexes In Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I recently noticed that after upgrading from community edition to enterprise edition simple label lookups like

MATCH (n:Resource) RETURN n LIMIT 5

Take very long. When I ran PROFILE, I noticed that all label lookups were doing AllNodesScan instead of NodeByLabelScan. I don't recall deleting any special indexes for node labels, but if I did, is there a way to recreate them to get fast NodeByLabelScan lookups again?

Have tried scouring the internet for ways to recreate these indexes to no avail.

Comment: which version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I was given a solution by someone on the Neo4j forum. I had likely accidentally deleted this index somehow as I had to delete all my BTREE indexes upgrading to Neo4j v5 and must have deleted the token index, too.

```
CREATE LOOKUP INDEX node_label for (n) on each labels(n)
```

did the trick :)